# Outliner -> vertex group select, not yet implemented: is it a bug?

Tags: vertex-groups

Blender 2.69 on Ubuntu 14.04..

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can select the vertex groups via the outliner (because it is not yet implemented), but you still have to select it via the properties panel --> Data object data --> vertex groups
(in version 2.75 it is also not yet implemented)

Comment: How is it still not implemented over 4 years later?